# Issue with conversion QByteArray to char*

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I faced an issue, which I can not explain when converting `QByteArray` to `const char*` not inline. Here is an example:

```
QString string1("ABCDEFGHI");
const char* stringData1 = string1.toUtf8().constData();
qDebug() << "String:" << string1 << "\nbytearray:" << string1.toUtf8()
         << "\ndata immediate:" << string1.toUtf8().constData() << "\ndata stored:" << stringData1;

QString string2("ABCDEFGHJ");
const char* stringData2 = string2.toUtf8().constData();
qDebug() << "String:" << string2 << "\nbytearray:" << string2.toUtf8()
         << "\ndata immediate:" << string2.toUtf8().constData() << "\ndata stored:" << stringData2;
```

I get the following output:

```
String: "ABCDEFGHI" 
bytearray: "ABCDEFGHI" 
data immediate: ABCDEFGHI 
data stored: 

String: "ABCDEFGHJ" 
bytearray: "ABCDEFGHJ" 
data immediate: ABCDEFGHJ 
data stored: ABCDEFGHJ
```

The output of `data stored` is not guaranteed to be wrong in case 1, but correct in case 2. I can swap cases 1 and 2, and the result will be the same - wrong in case 1, but correct in case 2.

Inline conversion seems to work just fine.

Do you see any issues with conversion from `QByteArray` to `const char*` if a `const char*` variable is used to store the result?

Comment: You're calling `QByteArray::constData` on the *temporary* `QByteArray` returned by `QString::toUtf8`.  So `stringData1` and `stringData2` are dangling pointers: undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toUtf8` returns an object whose lifetime ends at the end of the expression.
`constData` returns a pointer into this temporary object.
Thus, you're using dangling pointers and the behaviour is undefined.

You need to extend the lifetime of the converted string:

```
QString string1("ABCDEFGHI");
QByteArray utfString = string1.toUtf8();
const char* stringData1 = utfString.constData();
```

Answer (score 0):

This call `string1.toUtf8().constData()` consists of two consequential ones: `QString::toUtf8()`which produces a temporary `QByteArray`, and `QByteArray::constData()` which returns a pointer to a temporary object, which eventually getting destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to get a QString variable, convert it to QByteArray and finally const char* is this:

```cpp
QString var1 = ui->lineEdit->text().toUtf8();
QByteArray ba = var1.toLocal8Bit();
const char *var1final = ba.data();
```

The value of QString is collected by **Ui**, in lineEdit.